Sphinx-index.rst file auto update
Is there a way to auto-update index.rst file to include all the .rst files generated?
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

Here is the current content of the index.rst
I want to auto update the file and the content will be like
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   doc1
   doc2

doc1 and doc2 are generated rst files

I would write own script in Python to generate index.rst - maybe I would use jinja to create template for this. But even normal f-string could resolve it - f"text {place_for_toctree} other text"

I didn't test it but I found sphinx-autogen — Sphinx documentation

I would use globbing. In this case, replace docN with *.
